# How to retrieve the Identity Resolving Key (IRK) of a bluetooth device on a windows PC

Tags: bluetooth-low-energy, home-assistant

I'm trying to retrieve the IRK of a BLE device to use with Home Assistant's "Private BLE Device" integration, but I don't know where to find it.

I've tried looking in the Device Manager and tried a Python script to retrieve it but neither worked. Is there even a way to find a BLE device's IRK on a Windows 11 laptop?